# Automatic segmenting of MIDI file into phrases for dataset

Tags: parsing, dataset, midi

I am doing some research that involves first building a dataset of short musical phrases. Ideally, this would be done based on some machine learning algorithm to guess the structure of the music and split it into phrases accordingly. Unfortunately, I have not found an implementation of such an algorithm, or even any clear evidence that such an algorithm exists.

Without such an algorithm, that next best thing would be to split up each midi file into groups of say 2-3 bars. I would also need to detect and remove empty segments. Is there a simple way to automate this? If I didn't need so much data, I would probably consider doing it by hand.

I am not tied to any particular language. I have looked at music21 which seems to support reading and editing MIDI files, but I haven't yet found what I am looking for.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Rowe's book 'Machine Musicianship' (MIT Press) has a chapter dealing with different approaches to segmenting musical data into phrases and detecting patterns. (Obviously, there's more to it than can fit in a SO response..)

Comment: Thanks for the response and the book recommendation, I will mark it for future reference. Meanwhile I am resorting to enlisting a small army to manually segment the melodies.